# LWC - Multiple table rows for each iteration in for:each - where do I put the key?

Tags: lightning-web-components, for

I am converting an Aura component to LWC, and have hit one issue. In the Aura component two table rows are created for each iteration. However, in the LWC, I cannot create two rows for each iteration, as I need ot set a key on a single parent node. I cannot figure out how to create two rows in each iteration.

I thought about surrounding the two tr tags with another tag, but the Mozilla Developer Documentation is pretty clear that the standard defines only the following parents are allowed for tr:

> `<table>` (only if the table has no child `<tbody>`
> element, and even then only after any `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, and
> `<thead>` elements); otherwise, the parent must be `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or
> `<tfoot>`
> [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

So, in short - how can I iterate over an array, and generate two table rows for each iteration, something like so? Where would I put the key? Is this possible?

```
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <tr><td>First row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second row</td></tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You can use the same key for both of the rows.

```
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>Second row</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Or you can create a unique key for each of the rows. Let's say `firstRowId`, `secondRowId`. Which you can assign to `item.id + "0"` and `item.id + "1"`

```
<template for:each={items} for:item="item">
    <tr key={item.firstRowId}>
        <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr key={item.secondRowId}>
        <td>Second row</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Simple as that eh? From the documentation I thought that the key needed to uniquely identify the parent element. Guess not.

Comment: its needed but as they are in same iteration it doesn't give an error..

Comment: Okay, so now that I have developed things a bit further, I get an error in teh console, and the behaviour no longer works as expected - when the fetching from server happens and re-rendering occurs.

Comment: what error you are getting? @bpilling

Comment: Okay, so I tried your second suggestion, and generated a new unique key that i use (simply incrementing a property in my javascript file every time it is used) - and that worked a treat. So in summary, I couldn't use the same key for both, but I could use an actual unique one. Thanks Rahul!